# How can I alter the webform based on it's parent paragraph type?

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-webform

The target for me is a custom paragraph type that I made which allows you to embed a webform in it. I need to update the submit callback for only those forms which are added in this paragraph type.

I have used the hook to alter the form, but I can't seem to find the reference to the parent paragraph type in that hook to put the condition.

Alternatively, when I am preprocessing the paragraph, I have access to the content and in turn the webform entity, but I can't update the form settings from that function?

Edit: The ultimate goal is for me to handle the ajax submit by default method but in my custom callback function so that I want to override the response with an additional command.

I am able to do it currently, but this approach alters all the forms.

Any help would be appreciated. I have not added the code blocks here since the implementation is pretty generic, but if somebody wants to take a look at the code, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The `$form_id` is always in the form `webform_submission_<webform_id>_<field_machine_name>_<delta>_add_form` (see my example below)
[image]
So you can check if `$form_id` start with `webform_submission_<webform_id>_<field_machine_name>` like this:

```php
function <your_module>_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if (strpos($form_id, 'webform_submission_<webform_id>_<field_machine_name>') === 0) {
        // Your logic
    }
}
```